Accessing Shared State in a Non-Single-SPA Micro-Frontend Application
I'm building an application using a micro-frontend architecture. Here are the different micro-apps I have:

SpaApp1: An Angular application for core services.
SpaApp2: An Angular application for the login page.
@org/SharedApp: A shared application responsible for maintaining the state (e.g., auth token, user info) across all micro-apps.
@org/root-config: The root application that imports and connects all other micro-apps.

In addition to these, I have App3, a NestJS application (not currently integrated with single-spa) that makes backend API calls. SpaApp1 uses GraphQL to query responses from App3.
I want to use the shared state from @org/SharedApp (which contains the auth token and user information) within App3. Currently, it seems like I would need to integrate App3 with the single-spa library to achieve this. Is there an alternative approach that would allow App3 to access the shared state from @org/SharedApp without integrating with single-spa?
I tried accessing the shared state maintained by @org/SharedApp in my NestJS application (App3) to use the authentication token and user information. Since App3 is not integrated with the single-spa framework, I attempted to find an alternative method for sharing state between the micro-frontend Angular apps (SpaApp1 and SpaApp2) and the NestJS backend.
I was expecting to be able to directly import and utilize the shared state from @org/SharedApp in App3, or find another way to securely pass the authentication token and user information to the backend services without exposing them to the browser.
